# This code is displaying an INF value on the screen

Tags: php

The following code is displaying INF as the result. How can I fix it?

```
<?php
    function fibonacci($n)
    {
        $a = 1;
        $b = 1;
        $result = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i=$i+1)
        {
            $sum = $a + $b;
            $a = $b;
            $b = $sum;
            if ($a % 2 == 0)
            {
                $result = $result + $a;
            }
        }
        echo "<br/>" . $result;
    }

    echo fibonacci(400000);
?>
```

Comment: Use a lower value than 400000 in your call to fibonacci... you're reaching the point where the math has exceeded the highest possible float in PHP, so you're getting a result of INFINITE

Comment: Alternatively, switch to using the bcmath functions

Comment: I can't use lower value because I'm try to solve puzzle. Here is puzzle (By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.)

Comment: Then you've goofed up the logic. Multiple times.

Comment: You're looking for the values that don't exceed 4 million, not 4 million different values

Comment: Looks like one from Project Euler ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following implements your logic using bcmath to prevent the INF error.

```
function fibonacci($n)
{
    $a = '1'; $b = '1'; $result = '0';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $sum = bcadd($a,$b);
        $a = $b;
        $b = $sum;
        if (bcmod($a,'2') == '0') {
            $result = bcadd($result,$a);
        }
    }
    echo "<br />".$result;
}
```

As your fibonacci function doesn't actually return any value, there's no point in echo fibonacci(400000)

**EDIT**

However, your logic is completely flawed. The following should give you the correct result for the problem you're trying to solve (again using bcmath):

```
function fibonacci($n)
{
    $a = '0'; $b = '1'; $sum = '0';
    $sum = '0';
    do {
        $fib = bcadd($a,$b);
        $a = $b;
        $b = $fib;
        if (bccomp($fib,$n) == -1) {
            if (bcmod($fib,'2') == '0') {
                $sum = bcadd($sum,$fib);
            }
        }
        ++$i;
    } while (bccomp($fib,$n) == -1);
    return $sum;
}


echo fibonacci(4000000);
```

Rather than simply executing it to get the result, look to see how it works and what it's actually doing

Comment: And please let us know if it executes in less time that it takes the sun to explode. kthnxbye

Comment: @mhughes - The EDITed code for the correct logic is pretty quick (0.0005 seconds on me little dev box)

Answer (score 1):

The number is too big to display, and INF is a pretty good guess :) (fibonacci(1000) gives you a number with 210 digits).

100: 22 digits, 110: 24 digits, 120: 25 digits, 130: 27 digits

If you extrapolate that, you would end up with about (400000 / 10) * 2 = 80000 digits.